# Jensen inequality in measure theory : why doesn't the convex function need to be nonnegative?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, holder-inequality, jensen-inequality

[This section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form) of the Wikipedia article on [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) states that if $g$ is an integrable function on a measure space with mass $1$ and $\varphi$ is a convex function, then
$$\varphi \left( \int g \right) \leq \int \varphi \circ g $$
What troubles me is that I can see no mention of a hypothesis ensuring that $\varphi \circ g$ actually has an integral (like that it is integrable or else $\varphi$ is nonnegative).
I assumed it was simply missing, but then I noticed that not only does the same article [in French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/In%C3%A9galit%C3%A9_de_Jensen#Th%C3%A9orie_de_la_mesure) also omit these hypotheses but furthermore, it even bothers to mention that the integral on the right may be infinite, suggesting in my opinion that $\varphi$ should be assumed to be nonnegative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\varphi \circ g$ always has integrable negative part so that the integral on the right hand side is well-defined via
$$\int \varphi \circ g d \mu = \int (\varphi \circ g)^+ d\mu - \int(\varphi \circ g)^- d\mu$$

To prove this, note that convex functions possess subderivatives so that there are numbers $a,b$ such that
$$ax + b \leq \varphi(x)$$

In particular, $(\varphi \circ g) \geq a g + b$ so that
$$0 \leq (\varphi \circ g)^{-} \leq |a g + b| \in L^1$$